# JExcel overlay - unrecognized expression: #

Tags: jquery

I'm using this JQuery library : https://bossanova.uk/jexcel
Because it don't have all the fonctionnality I need, I'm overlaying the code.
All of my adds are good, but the last one (a very simple one) crash everything ...

The table is added into the div you set, for exemple, you have a div in html with the id : "rabbit" and the library will add the table into the div.

I'm tring to add a div between them like this :

```
/* Between div */
var parent_main = document.createElement('div');
$(parent_main).prop('class', 'main');
$(parent_main).append(table);

/* Main object */
$(this).append(parent_main);
//$(this).append(table);
```

All of it is ok, the table is in my "rabbit" div, so where is the problem ?

Now when I click on a td of this table (to edit the content for exemple), I've got this error :
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqobU.png)

And it seems to be trigered at this line :

```
if ($.fn.jexcel.defaults[$.fn.jexcel.current].rowDrag == true && $(e.target).outerWidth() - e.offsetX < 8) {
```

So the question is : How to solve this please ? ^^

Answer (score 0):

You need to give us a more detailed example. Maybe you can use the native onload and add your div after the table is loaded.

```
$('#my').jexcel({
    data:data,
    colHeaders: ['Country', 'Food', 'Stock'],
    colWidths: [ 300, 100, 200 ],
    columns: [
        { type: 'autocomplete', source:countries },
        { type: 'dropdown', source:['Apples','Bananas','Carrots','Oranges','Cheese'] },
        { type: 'checkbox' },
        { type: 'text', readOnly:true },
    ],
    onload: function() {
        $('#my').append('<div>your new div</div>');
    }
});
```